# Why am I getting a 1064 error when I am using foreign key constraint?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using workbench for class and have to run this query and keep getting this:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '   CONSTRAINT `fk_artwork_artist`     FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`)     REFERENCE...' at line 10

I am using version 10.4.21 and i can't find anything about what the syntax is suppose to be other than what I already have. Below is the query.

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `art_gallery`.`artwork` (
      `artwork_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
      `artyear` INT(4) NOT NULL,
      `period` VARCHAR(25) NULL,
      `arttype` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
      `artfile` VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
      `artist_id` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`artwork_id`),
      INDEX `fk_artwork_artist_idx` (`artist_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_artwork_artist`
        FOREIGN KEY (`artist_id`)
        REFERENCES `art_gallery`.`artist` (`artist_id`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
    ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: It's not the foreign key it's NEAR the foreign key - mariadb does not have VISIBLE indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VISIBLE` keyword on the index was added in MariaDB-10.5.3 [MDEV-22199](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-22199). You appear to be using an earlier version.

To correct, you can just omit `VISIBLE`.

ref: [10.4 fiddle example](https://dbfiddle.uk/B1EDkZbm)